# Stop Windows 8 using "Large Icons" view

Tags: windows-8

I don't want Windows 8 to use large icons view. If I'm looking for a video file, chances are I need to sort it by date to see when I took it, etc, so I want details view. Always.

You can disable the preview icons, but Windows 8 still insists that what I want is to see large icons, albeit now without the pretty preview. If I use "Apply to all folders", well it doesn't.

Any ideas? I just want it to use details view by default not large icons view when I have a folder full of video.

Comment: Windows 8.1 addresses this problem until its released your stuck with the the two sizes of icons.

Comment: @Ramhound: He says "I want details view. Always." Are you saying this is not possible in Win8?

Comment: @Karan - I am saying the update will address the problem, I wasn't sure if it was possible, to force the tiles to be a certain size.  That is one of the problems the update will address the lack of customability within the Start Screen itself.

Comment: @Ramhound: You might want to re-read the question. He's clearly talking about Large Icons and Details view in Windows/File Explorer, not tile sizes on the Start Screen.

Comment: Yes absolutely, the problem is in explorer in Windows 8, not the start menu. If you browse to a folder containing video files, it switches to large icons which is next to useless.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Reset Folders**, then set all folders to use the **General items** template, switch to **Details** view and **Apply to (all) Folders**:

[image: 1]

Comment: It's funny this didn't work the first time I tried it, thus the post. I'm wondering if I didn't reset folders the first time. Also, the file dialog box would ignore my choice, so even when explorer got the message, file open dialog hadn't. Solved this by simply changing the view in the actual dialog.

Comment: Unfortunately the "automatic folder type discovery" anti-feature will override this action. Every time.